# Posting text of div with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to post the content of div(text) to a php page with ajax, i have already this script which post all the input fields of the three forms

```
.on('actionclicked.fu.wizard' , function(e, info){
    if(info.step == 3 ) {
        var dataString = $("#form1, #form2, #form3").serialize();
        var mydiv = $('#mydiv').html();
        $.ajax({
            data: dataString + mydiv,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'confirmation.php',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                message : 'you request was submitted'
            }
        });               
    }
})
```

but i need to post also the text of the div in the php page i use 
`$mydiv =$_REQUEST['mydiv'];`
I can echo all the other fields but nothing return for $mydiv.

Answer (score 0):

```
`.on('actionclicked.fu.wizard' , function(e, info){
        if(info.step == 3 ) {
           var a = $("#form1").serialize();
           var b = $("#form2").serialize();
           var c = $("#form3").serialize();
           var d = $(#mydiv).text();
           data = {};
           data['astring'] = a;
           data['bstring'] = b;
           data['cstring'] = c;
           data['ddivtext'] = d;
           $.ajax({
               data: data,
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: "json",
               url: 'confirmation.php',
               cache: false,
               success: function(data) {
                   message : 'you request was submitted'
               }
           });               
        }
    })
```

Comment: Excuse me Newbie i didn't understand well your answer can you tell me where putting this piece of code into mine please;

Comment: Excuse me, i was not precise.  Also added dataType

Comment: Thank you, i removed the datatype because it a simple echo from the php page, but now i can get the value of the div but not the value of the other fields :/

Comment: i made a typo there, before the equal sign...edited it...how about making 3 different dataString variables,each holding one serialized form? after that you can form 3 more data packages inside the ajax...it could make it easy to follow the posted data parts.

Comment: i ve tried this also but always i can get only the text of the div only

Comment: can you please post the code you have in the target php file? confirmation.php? especially the POST variable checking/handling...

Comment: On the post side you will have `$_POST['astring'];$_POST['bstring'];`  and so on ...

Comment: thank you newbie, i used another methode, i ve appended the text of the div into a hidden input field.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <h1>This is a page</h1>
</div>

$("#post").click(function(){
        var htmlData = $("#myDiv").html();
        $.post('postPage.php', {'html': htmlData },function(response){
            // 
        });
```